# Current Screen Size in Python3 with PyQt5

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

Is there an alternative in Qt5 python3 to the following code :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/153549/how-to-detect-a-computers-physical-screen-size-in-gtk

```
from gi.repository import Gdk
s = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
print(s.get_width(), s.get_height())
```

Comment: In `Pyside6`, use `widget.screen().size()` for any `QWidget`.

Answer (score 36):

You can get the [primary screen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen) from the `QApplication`, which returns a [QScreen](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) object giving access to many useful properties:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

screen = app.primaryScreen()
print('Screen: %s' % screen.name())
size = screen.size()
print('Size: %d x %d' % (size.width(), size.height()))
rect = screen.availableGeometry()
print('Available: %d x %d' % (rect.width(), rect.height()))
```

Note that the `primaryScreen` method is static, so if you've already created an instance of QApplication elsewhere in your application, can easily get a QScreen object later on like this:

```
screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
```

Comment: Great,  your code allows me to have more information on my screen

Comment: Note: You can get current application instance by calling `QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()`. This was useful for me because I want to get dimensions inside `QMainWindow` subclass

Comment: @Omkar76 I updated my answer with an easier way to get the screen object.

Comment: In Jupyter / JupyterLab I do app = QtWidgets.QApplication([""])

Comment: What if your app is not shown on the primary screen?

Comment: @bers The "primary screen" just means whatever screen is associated with the application (i.e. its default screen).

Answer (score 15):

The following python3 code allows to get screen size but is there an alternative to
`QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)` method :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def main():
"""
allow you to get size of your current screen
-1 is to precise that it is the current screen
"""
    sizeObject = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)
    print(" Screen size : "  + str(sizeObject.height()) + "x"  + str(sizeObject.width()))   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why does `screenGeometry(-1)` work though? The code above works, but is really unobvious...

Comment: `screenGeometry(0)` makes more sense (null QWidget) and seems to work too. Good solution avoiding to get the QApplication, thanks!

Comment: `QDesktopWidget` is gone in Qt 6: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/widgets-changes-qt6.html#qdesktopwidget-and-qapplication-desktop

Answer (score 5):

The value for `screenGeometry()` is the display you take a look at. 
0 is the main screen, 1, 2 indicates further monitors installed.

To list all availible displays:

```
def screen_resolutions():
    for displayNr in range(QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenCount()):
        sizeObject = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(displayNr)
        print("Display: " + str(displayNr) + " Screen size : " + str(sizeObject.height()) + "x" + str(sizeObject.width()))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
self.desktop = QApplication.desktop()
self.screenRect = self.desktop.screenGeometry()
self.height = self.screenRect.height()
self.width = self.screenRect.width()
```

You can see here - https://www.programmersought.com/article/58831562998/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Screen information is available from the QApplication object as noted by ekhumoro. However, there should be only one global instance of QApplication. It is often set in the main script of a PyQt Gui application:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
def main():
...
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   window = MainWindow()
   window.show
    
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That's probably not where you want to work with screen properties.

As pointed out by Omkar76, to access the global instance from elsewhere (e.g. in MainWindow()) use its instance() function. You can then use its [primaryScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#primaryScreen-prop) property to get access to the many useful pieces of information available from the [QScreen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html) object:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
       # Window dimensions
       app = QApplication.instance()
       screen = app.primaryScreen()
       geometry = screen.availableGeometry()
       self.setFixedSize(geometry.width() * 0.8, geometry.height() * 0.7)
```

[QDesktopWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) is obsolete and so should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

With QDesktopWidget being obsolete, you will need to use the screenAt method of QApplication. primaryScreen is static and does not take into account the current Screen of the application:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
       # Window dimensions
       app = QApplication.instance()
       screen = app.screenAt(self.pos())
       geometry = screen.availableGeometry()
       self.setFixedSize(geometry.width() * 0.8, geometry.height() * 0.7)
```

Answer (score -1):

i honestly don't know why it's always such a hustle to find pyqt5 answers,but anyway i think this is what you were looking for .

```
print(self.frameSize())
```

Comment: this would return the size of the qt5 window, OP asked for the screen size for the display